# How to make Emacs pickup the correct python in Snow Leopard?

Tags: python, emacs, path, osx-snow-leopard

Related to my previous question: [Pymacs not starting on Emacs24 Carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386205/pymacs-not-starting-on-emacs24-carbon/)

Ropemacs won't load, since emacs isn't seeing the correct site-packages directory (see the previous question for example output).

I'm using Snow Leopard, with the dev version of emacs24 installed through homebrew.

```
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 24.0.93.1
```

Python is also installed through homebrew, and preferred by setting it at the front of my path.

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.2
```

I use zsh as my login shell.

If I type `M-! python --version` into emacs, it returns `Python 2.6.1`, even though in my shell, `/usr/local/bin` is ahead of `/usr/bin` in my PATH. Indeed, emacs thinks my path is "reversed", in the sense that the default Python framework is ahead of my preferred python. I think this may be caused by `path_helper`.

zsh PATH:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/jrhorn424/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin: *snip*
```

emacs PATH:

```
M-! echo $PATH [RET]
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin: *snip*
```

I have the zsh path copied into `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`, but that doesn't prevent `/usr/bin` from prefixing in emacs.

Possibly related: [Emacs is ignoring my path when it runs a compile command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266905/emacs-is-ignoring-my-path-when-it-runs-a-compile-command)

I've implemented that solution, which is included in [this list of solutions to the PATH problem](http://dskang.com/2011/04/28/emacs-path-problem-on-os-x/), but I'm still getting the results above. Perhaps these solutions are a bit dated?

Telling me to upgrade to Lion, if you can convince me it will solve my issue, is OK, but I would prefer to stay with Snow Leopard for now.

Comment: I found the answer at superuser. I wouldn't object to this being moved to superuser (my apologies for not realizing this before I posted). This could probably be marked as a duplicate of [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/304220/how-can-i-update-the-default-python-installation-fix-my-path-on-mac-os-x-10-6-7) though I didn't find it using my original search terms. Perhaps this could be kept around as a pointer to the other question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/etc/path` (as an administrator) and move the line `/usr/local/bin` to the top of the file.